# Golang: How to check a file whether is a shortcut file on windows using Golang?

Tags: windows, go, shortcut

I know how to check a file whether is a symbolic link file on linux, such as:

```golang
func IsSymLink(path string) bool {
    if info, err := os.Lstat(path); err == nil && info.Mode()&os.ModeSymlink != 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

But, how to check a file whether is a shortcut file on windows uing Golang? who can help me, thx.

Comment: I assume you need to check the file extension in this case. 
As far as I can remember and confirmed with this Wikipedia article it is an `.lnk` file. 
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortcut_(computing))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows shortcut files should have an extension `.lnk`.
You could start by checking for that.

```
func IsWinShortcut(path string) bool {
    return filepath.Ext(path) == ".lnk"
}
```